# docker-compose not downloading additions to requirements.txt file

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a Django project running in docker.
When I add some packages to my requirments.txt file, they don't get downloaded when I run docker-compose up

Here is the relevant commands from my Dockerfile:

```
ADD ./evdc/requirements.txt /opt/evdc-venv/
ADD ./env-requirements.txt /opt/evdc-venv/

# Active venv
RUN . /opt/evdc-venv/bin/activate && pip install -r /opt/evdc-        venv/requirements.txt
RUN . /opt/evdc-venv/bin/activate && pip install -r /opt/evdc-venv/env-requirements.txt
```

It seems docker is using a cached version of my requirements.txt file, as when I shell into the container, the requirements.txt file in /opt/evdc-venv/requirements.txt does not include the new packages.
Is there some way I can delete this cached version of requirements.txt?

- Dev OS: Windows 10
- Docker: 17.03.0-ce
- docker-compose: 1.11.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker-compose up` doesn't build a new image unless you have the `build` section defined with your Dockerfile and you pass it the `--build` parameter. Without that, it will reuse the existing image.

If your docker-compose.yml does not include the build section, and your build your images with `docker build ...`, then after you recreate your image, a `docker-compose up` will recreate the impacted containers.

Comment: Or you can docker-compose build

Comment: Yes, only left that out of my answer since that's one extra step in the first scenario, and doesn't work in the second scenario when you don't have the build section in the docker-compose.yml. But assuming you have a build section, that works too.

Comment: Yes.  Sometimes you want to build, sometimes you want to fire everything up, sometimes you want both :)